# how to instantiate wchar_t** array

Tags: c++

how to instantiate `wchar_t**` `wchar_t*` array?

I tried:

```
wchar_t** myData;
myData = new wchar_t[3];
```

but failed. How to overcome this problem?

Any helps would be very appreciated.

Comment: new wchar_t returns `wchar_t *`, what you need is `new wchar_t*[3]` to return `wchar_t**`

Comment: Maybe you shoul tell us what was the error compiler gave you? We are not mediums.

Comment: @Mesut is there exact goal you are trying to achieve? In modern C++ we tend to avoid raw arrays (and especially, arrays of arrays ) and raw `operator new` calls. Maybe if you tell us your exact goal, we could advise you more appropriate solution.

Comment: by seeing the usage `new` looks pretty much C++. Why'd you tag `C` ?

Comment: Thanks guy, I'm a C# developper. But I had to work on a C++ project for a short time. the following answer solved my problem. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
//ugly code
wchar_t** myData = new wchar_t*[3];
myData[0] = new wchar_t[2];
myData[1] = new wchar_t[3];
myData[2] = NULL;
```

Of course you need to initialize each component, e.g.

```
myData[0][0] = (wchar_t)'W';
myData[0][1] = (wchar_t)0;
```

Actually, you should not code something that ugly. Maybe use `std::vector<std::wstring>`

Comment: I'd recommend zero initializing the new arrays: `new wchar_t*[3]()`